# Trying to run Nunit test with SQLite database in memory

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, xamarin, nunit

I'm new to Xamarin/C# and I'm trying to run some tests on my Data Access Layer. I'm using SQLite and by doing some research I found out that I can use this string `"DataSource=:memory:"` when creating my database so I can load the database without having to load a file from somewhere or form the device.

So, I tried this:

```
[Test]
public void test()
{            
    Database database = new Database("DataSource=:memory:");
}
```

But when I run the test, the following exception is thrown:

> System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I have the sqlite-net-pcl on both my projects (Nunit project and Shared code project).

Am I doing something wrong? If so, could someone point me in the right direction? I've trying to find a solution to this problem and this seems to me as the best (easiest) solution. But if there is another approach, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Are you adding the SQLite "native" package to your NUnit project? Choose the correct one based upon the platform that you are running your NUnit tests on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to fix the problem myself. The issue was that a DLL was missing from the `/[your-project-name]/bin/debug`/ folder. I was able to download the missing DLL [here](https://sqlite.org/download.html).